# R vectorized matrix into numeric data frame with preserving factors

Tags: r, matrix, vector, dataframe, double

i have matrices given by folloing way:

```
m <- as.matrix(rbind(c("State", "Murder", "Assault", "UrbanPop", "Rape", "Group"),
c("Alabama", 13.2, 236, 58, 21.2, "A"),
c("Alaska", 10.0, 263, 48, 44.5, "A"),
c("Arizona", 8.1, 294, 80, 31.0, "A"),
c("Arkansas", 8.8, 190, 50, 19.5, "A"),
c("California", 9.0, 276, 91, 40.6, "A"),
c("Colorado", 7.9, 204, 78, 38.7, "A"),
c("Connecticut", 3.3, 110, 77, 11.1, "A"),
c("Delaware", 5.9, 238, 72, 15.8, "A"),
c("Florida", 15.4, 335, 80, 31.9, "A"),
c("Georgia", 17.4, 211, 60, 25.8, "A"),
c("Hawaii", 5.3, 46, 83, 20.2, "A"),
c("Idaho", 2.6, 120, 54, 14.2, "A"),
c("Illinois", 10.4, 249, 83, 24.0, "A"),
c("Indiana", 7.2, 113, 65, 21.0, "A"),
c("Iowa", 2.2, 56, 57, 11.3, "A"),
c("Kansas", 6.0, 115, 66, 18.0, "A"),
c("Kentucky", 9.7, 109, 52, 16.3, "A"),
c("Louisiana", 15.4, 249, 66, 22.2, "A"),
c("Maine", 2.1, 83, 51, 7.8, "B"),
c("Maryland", 11.3, 300, 67, 27.8, "B"),
c("Massachusetts", 4.4, 149, 85, 16.3, "B"),
c("Michigan", 12.1, 255, 74, 35.1, "B"),
c("Minnesota", 2.7, 72, 66, 14.9, "B"),
c("Mississippi", 16.1, 259, 44, 17.1, "B"),
c("Missouri", 9.0, 178, 70, 28.2, "B"),
c("Montana", 6.0, 109, 53, 16.4, "B"),
c("Nebraska", 4.3, 102, 62, 16.5, "C"),
c("Nevada", 12.2, 252, 81, 46.0, "C"),
c("New_Hampshire", 2.1, 57, 56, 9.5, "C"),
c("New_Jersey", 7.4, 159, 89, 18.8, "C"),
c("New_Mexico", 11.4, 285, 70, 32.1, "C"),
c("New_York", 11.1, 254, 86, 26.1, "C"),
c("North_Carolina", 13.0, 337, 45, 16.1, "C"),
c("North_Dakota", 0.8, 45, 44, 7.3, "C"),
c("Ohio", 7.3, 120, 75, 21.4, "D"),
c("Oklahoma", 6.6, 151, 68, 20.0, "D"),
c("Oregon", 4.9, 159, 67, 29.3, "D"),
c("Pennsylvania", 6.3, 106, 72, 14.9, "D"),
c("Rhode_Island", 3.4, 174, 87, 8.3, "D"),
c("South_Carolina", 14.4, 279, 48, 22.5, "D"),
c("South_Dakota", 3.8, 86, 45, 12.8, "D"),
c("Tennessee", 13.2, 188, 59, 26.9, "D"),
c("Texas", 12.7, 201, 80, 25.5, "D"),
c("Utah", 3.2, 120, 80, 22.9, "D"),
c("Vermont", 2.2, 48, 32, 11.2, "D"),
c("Virginia", 8.5, 156, 63, 20.7, "D"),
c("Washington", 4.0, 145, 73, 26.2, "D"),
c("West_Virginia", 5.7, 81, 39, 9.3, "D"),
c("Wisconsin", 2.6, 53, 66, 10.8, "D"),
c("Wyoming", 6.8, 161, 60, 15.6, "D")))
```

i need to convert this into data.frame (or table) with preserving column and rownames, numericity of numbers and convert anything else (in this example column 'Group') into factors. (Data are'nt always in this format, so code has to be general.)

(Optional step is then to remove one column by given name, that's the reason for using data.frame, as it is very easy to do.)

Then, resulting data.frame (or table, or matrix) is passed into 'scale' function.

My solution consists of several steps:

```
data <- m[-1,-1]
colnames(data) <- m[1,-1]
rownames(data) <- m[-1,1][m[-1,1]!='']
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

now i have data.frame, but it cannot be passed into *scale()* function ("Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric"). If i use *data.matrix(data)* function, factors are integered fine, but all doubles are converted into integers too. I am stuck at this for hours.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Actually `data.matrix(data)` will completely mess up all your factors.

Comment: Practically, i need anything to accomplish the goals above, that means preserve column and row names, optionaly remove given column by name and then the rest of data put into scale

Comment: After you run your first three lines, **don't** run `data <- as.data.frame(data)`, instead, do: `data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ; scale(data.matrix(data[-5]))`. In other words, don't use `data.matrix` on factors *and* don't use `scale` on `chracter`s (your `Group` column).

Comment: David Arenburg: stringsAsFactors helped nicely, but i need to convert 'Group' into factors, so it would be included in following calculations... Then the question is practically very easy -- how to convert column (of apriori unknown index) into factors?

Comment: After you do `data <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` run `data <- data.frame(lapply(data, type.convert))`

Comment: I have no idea what you talking about

Comment: David Arenburg: After lapply (should it convert 'Group' names into factors?), data frame is unchanged except missing row names; Veerendra Gadekar: actually because resulting 'mmm' dataframe has the same problems as described above -- everything there is character string and after data.matrixing it, doubles are integered

Comment: I still have no idea what you talking about, I've posted as an answer and provided `str` too as proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll move this to an answer, as it seems not working via comments. You can do the following

```
data <- data.frame(lapply(data.frame(m[-1,-1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE), type.convert))
```

Which will convert all the columns of the matrix to the correct formats

```
str(data)
# 'data.frame':  50 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ X1: num  13.2 10 8.1 8.8 9 7.9 3.3 5.9 15.4 17.4 ...
# $ X2: int  236 263 294 190 276 204 110 238 335 211 ...
# $ X3: int  58 48 80 50 91 78 77 72 80 60 ...
# $ X4: num  21.2 44.5 31 19.5 40.6 38.7 11.1 15.8 31.9 25.8 ...
# $ X5: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Then, you can set your column/row names as you wish

```
colnames(data) <- m[1,-1]
rownames(data) <- m[-1,1][m[-1,1]!='']
```

For `scale` you can do

```
scale(data[-5])
```

---

**Edit per OPs comment**.

As I already said several times, using `data.matrix` on `factor`s is simply wrong and it will completely mess up your data. Consider the following example

```
data.matrix(data.frame(A = factor(c("A", "B")),
                       B = factor(10:11),
                       C = factor(c("22-11-2014", "23-11-2014"))))
#      A B C
# [1,] 1 1 1
# [2,] 2 2 2
```

`data.matrix` returned identical results for these completely different values.

Now back to your real data, If you want to avoid running `scale` on factors and you apriori don't know which columns are factors, you can simply create an index which will identify numeric columns and then run `scale` only on them, for example

```
indx <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
scale(data[indx])
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice that there are more answers. YES, after all you wrote + aplying data.matrix(data) i get resulting matrix where factors are converted into integers so they can be included in any following calcultions. (Using directly [-5] was not suitable for me as i don't know structure of data i'll get on input.)

Comment: Thank you very much both David Arenburg and Veerendra Gadekar!

Comment: As I said, I don't like your `data.matrix(data)` approach. See my edit which illustrates why.

Comment: It's all right, "group" column with characters might be (on input) filled by integers (instead of characters) which will mean group id as well. Thus, data.matrix producing unique integer for every columnwise-item-class is exactly the desired behavior which i wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Read it as `data.frame` and do this later

```
m = data.frame(rbind.... you data here as above)

rownames(m) = m$X1 
colnames(m) = c(t(m[1,]))
req.df  = m[-1,-1]
```

Comment: this is nicier than the code i have, but it seems it's not compatible with David Arenburgs steps above :-/

Answer (score 0):

Below is a quick trial that can preserve numeric and factor types.

```
# convert into data frame
df <- as.data.frame(m[2:nrow(m), 2:ncol(m)], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# set names
names(df) <- m[1, 2:ncol(m)]    
rownames(df) <- m[2:nrow(m), 1]
# convert types into numeric or factor
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.na(as.numeric(x[1]))) as.factor(x) else  as.numeric(x))

str(df)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Murder  : num  13.2 10 8.1 8.8 9 7.9 3.3 5.9 15.4 17.4 ...
 $ Assault : num  236 263 294 190 276 204 110 238 335 211 ...
 $ UrbanPop: num  58 48 80 50 91 78 77 72 80 60 ...
 $ Rape    : num  21.2 44.5 31 19.5 40.6 38.7 11.1 15.8 31.9 25.8 ...
 $ Group   : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```